# Does Forefront identity manager 2010 R2 SP1 support Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint, windows-server-2008-r2, identity-management

As per pre-requisite documentation FIM portal `2010 R2 SP1` supports Internet Explorer 9,8,7 and 6. 
Is Internet Explorer 11 officially supported for FIM Portal 4.1.3419 ( 2010 R2 SP1) running on `Windows 2008 R2 SP1`?

If not, can you please suggest the `FIM` version that supports IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 is also supported as indicated in the FIM software requirement:

> *Other browsers* which support Javascript, have cookies enabled, and
>   support CSS 3.0 media queries.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh332708%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

IE 11 supports javascript, can enable cookies and has CSS 3.0 media queries support as well http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries